# Insert more than one Many-to-Many data with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model in .Net Core API which includes four Many-to-Many relationships. I wanted to add them with only one HTTP request. I cannot find any answer in any forum (or maybe I haven't saw the answer). Here's the model with the Many-to-Many relationships:

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ColorsCategory> colorsCategories { get; set; }
        public List<ProductTypeCategory> ProductType { get; set; }
        public List<UsageCategory> Usage { get; set; }
        public List<SizeTypeCategory> SizeType { get; set; }
    }
```

The Many-to-Many relationship is already done and it's working, I can insert data but it always create the child (for example Usage), but it create a new one instead of get the Foreign key and add it to the `UsageCategory` table.

Here's the Context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
         //Colors
            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorsCategory>()
                .HasKey(p => new { p.ColorId, p.CategoryId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorsCategory>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(p => p.colorsCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ColorId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorsCategory>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Colors)
                .WithMany(p => p.ColorsCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        //ProductType
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTypeCategory>()
               .HasKey(p => new { p.ProductTypesId, p.CategoryId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTypeCategory>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProductType)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductTypesId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTypeCategory>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProductType)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            //Usage
            modelBuilder.Entity<UsageCategory>()
               .HasKey(p => new { p.UsageId, p.CategoryId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<UsageCategory>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(p => p.Usage)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.UsageId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UsageCategory>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(p => p.Usage)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            //Size Type
            modelBuilder.Entity<SizeTypeCategory>()
               .HasKey(p => new { p.SizeTypeId, p.CategoryId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<SizeTypeCategory>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(p => p.SizeType)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.SizeTypeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            modelBuilder.Entity<SizeTypeCategory>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(p => p.SizeType)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
```

The Controller is default generated by Visual Studio.